# Деление регулярного выражения на несколько условий

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, валидация

У меня есть `input` типа `password`. Для него, я использую регулярное выражение, которое выглядит так:

`/^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*()]).{3,}$/`

Это регулярное выражение отвечает за то, чтобы пароль обязательно содержал буквы, цифры и символы, независимо от порядка. Пожалуйста, помогите, разделить регулярное выражение так, чтобы оно должно было обязательно содержать, не зависимо от порядка: 1) Только символы и буквы 2) Только числа и символы 3) Только числа и буквы. Спасибо вам большое

Comment: тут настолько все очевидно, что даже непонятно, в чем проблема

Comment: прошу прощения, что тут не так?

Comment: не так то, что вы даже не попытались самостоятельно разобраться с задачей. Потому что если бы попытались, то уже давно все было бы сделано, настолько это простая задача

Answer (score -1):

Я так понял, вам нужна проверка для пароля, но при этом она не должна быть слишком лёгкая (только буквы), но и не должна быть слишком сложная (символы, буквы и числа).

Моё регулярное выражение это `^((([a-z]+\d+)|(\d+[a-z]+))[a-z\d]+)|((([!@#$%^&*()]+\d+)|(\d+[!@#$%^&*()]+))[!@#$%^&*()\d]+)|((([!@#$%^&*()]+[a-z]+)|([a-z]+[!@#$%^&*()]+))[!@#$%^&*()a-z]+)$`. Оно работает следующим образом:

1. Я делю выражение на несколько частей (в вашем случае 3) с помощью знака |;
2. ( ( ([a-z]+\d+) | (\d+[a-z]+) ) [a-z\d]+ ) - тут я проверяю начинается ли с буквы и продолжается ли цифрой (abc123), начинается ли с цифры и продолжается ли буквой (123abc), продолжается ли буквой или цифрой повторно (abc123abc).
3. Выражение также работает и на буквы, цифры и символы, так как оно не содержит условия "не включать выражение" - "(?![a-z])" (не включать a-z).

Вот моё решение вашей задачи:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]+\d+)|(\d+[a-z]+))[a-z\d]+)|((([!@#$%^&*()]+\d+)|(\d+[!@#$%^&*()]+))[!@#$%^&*()\d]+)|((([!@#$%^&*()]+[a-z]+)|([a-z]+[!@#$%^&*()]+))[!@#$%^&*()a-z]+)$/i);

console.log(regex.test('password')); // только буквы
console.log(regex.test('12345678')); // только цифры
console.log(regex.test('!!!!!!!!')); // только символы

console.log(regex.test('pass1234')); // буквы и цифры
console.log(regex.test('pass!!!!')); // буквы и символы
console.log(regex.test('1234!!!!')); // цифры и символы

console.log(regex.test('pass12!!')); // буквы, цифры, символы
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))), пытаюсь разобраться, какое именно выражение проверяет отдельное условие. Проверяет ли он сразу все условия? Потому что я кодом должен проверять каждое условие

Comment: Дайте мне 15 минут, я изменю свой ответ и распишу подробнее как работает данное регулярное выражение.